# Function call [table] not working

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have big problem.

The task is:

Write a function in C ++ that takes a array of ints `tab`, array size `n`, and the number `k`. The function returns returns `true` if each of the numbers in the table `tab`, at least k digits long, and `false` otherwise. Checking how many digits has the number should be included in the additional auxiliary functions that call from inside a basic function. You should also write the main function that reads the data, calls the base and outputs its result.

For calls (record [] is an array):
`f ([123,4425,2224,222,55553], 5, 3)`

The function should return true. Since each of the numbers 123,4425,2224,222,55553 at least three digital

Calls for:
`f ([123,4425,2,222,5], 5, 2)`

The function should return false

Because there are a number, for example 2 which is a digital one and is less than 1 k = 2

My code :

```
#include <iostream>

int ile_cyfr(int a)
{
    int temp=0;
    do
    {
        a = a/10;
        temp++;

    }  while(a>0);

    return temp;
}

bool funkcja(int *tab, int n, int k)
{
    bool stan = false;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        if (ile_cyfr(tab[i])<k)
        {
            stan = false;
            if (stan == false)
            {
                return stan;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stan = true;
            return stan;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int n=0, k=0;

    int *tab = new int[n];

    cout << "Podaj ilosc liczb: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    cout << "\nPodaj liczby: " << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> tab[i];
    }

    cout << "\nPodaj minimalna ilosc liczb: " << endl;
    cin >> k;

    cout << funkcja([444,856,671,321], n, k);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the line:

```
cout << funkcja([444,856,671,321], n, k);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the function `funkcja` is invalid. It returns true in case when the first element of the array has the number of digits greater than or equal to k. As I have understood you have to check that all elements of the array satisfy the condition.

The function can be written the following way

```
bool funkcja( const int *tab, int n, int k )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < n && !( ile_cyfr( tab[i] ) < k ) ) i++;

    return n != 0 && i = n;
}
```

As for this statement

```
cout << funkcja([444,856,671,321], n, k);
```

then it has an incorrect syntax.

You have to pass the variable `tab` as the first argument of the function call. These values 444,856,671,321 should be assigned to elements of the array pointed to by the pointer `tab`.

Thus write

```
cout << funkcja( tab, n, k );
```

Comment: @DawidIrzyk There was a typo in my function. There must be int i = 0;